# Making new verbs from the given words

Tags: word-request, verbs

The book asks me to make new verbs from the following words: *clear*, *noble*, *body*, *rate*, *store*.

For *clear*, I can use *clarify*; for *body*, *embody*; for *store*, *restore*.

For *noble*, I am not able to think of any new verb. For *rate*, *ratify* doesn't just satisfy me because I guess the meaning of *rate* and *ratify* are different, unlikely from *clear* and *clarify* which still have the same kind of meaning.

I wish somebody could help me with *noble* and *rate*.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *new verb*?  Your examples (*clarify*, *embody*, and *restore*) aren't particularly new.

Comment: Actually I didn't coin that term, so I can't define that properly. The exact wording in the book is 'Make new verbs from the following words. e.g. clear=clarify.'

Comment: I'm afraid your book isn't asking a very clear question, then.  My choice for *rate* would have been *rate*; *ratify* is cognate with but not derived from *rate*.  I don't know how to answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *noble*, I can think of [*ennoble*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ennoble). To bestow with *nobility*, I would choose *honor* or *grace*.

Answer (score 0):

[*nobilitate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nobilitate) - make someone a noble.

Note: *clear, rate* and *store* are verbs already.

For *body* there's *[embody](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embody)* - give a physical form.

Comment: Nobilate was obsolete in 1913, according to your link, so a bit of a stretch. Perhaps *ennoble*?

Comment: The OP was asked to make _new_ verbs. The fact _clear_ is already a verb doesn't change the task assigned to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

clear -> clarify, meaning to make clear.

noble -> ennoble, meaning to make noble. That word is used in the sense of "make this person a member of the nobility" and also "make an action grand or self-sacrificing".

body -> embody, to put something into concrete form.

rate is already a verb. I guess you could say rate -> rate.

Likewise store is already a verb.

Comment: By that standard, even *clear* is a verb.

Comment: True. That's a catch to a question like this: when you say to make a verb from a noun, there may be more than one verb having different meanings. If someone says, "You're meaning is not clear" I might reply, "Oh, let me clarify it for you." But if someone said, "The dishes have not been cleared from the table" I might say, "Oh, I will clear them." I wouldn't say, "I will clarify them."

Comment: that's an interesting point. So you think there is a new verb available that has somewhat same meaning as *rate*?

Comment: @Ramit I'm not sure what you mean by your question. There is a verb "rate", meaning to attach a rating to something. Like, "Please rate these chairs based on how comfortable they are."